# How would I animate cutting through cloth?

Tags: animation, modifiers, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to animate an object tearing through cloth (more of a banner) using the Boolean modifier. The animation in the viewport is almost workable, but baking and rendering the animation results in heavy deformation of the cloth object/simulation (see gif below).

I'm relatively new to Blender and this is my first time posting to Stack Exchange. I've been stuck on this for a week and there doesn't seem to be much information about this online, so any advice/suggestions/answers would be appreciated. I'm also posting the Blend file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello welcome to stack exchange, i think you should check this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icPQYWXhczM

Comment: @MichaelBenDavid Thank you :) Unfortunately the tutorial doesn't help with the issues I'm having

Comment: well there is a add-on (paid) for this, seems very good for this kind of effects...https://blendermarket.com/products/clothfx---dynamic-cloth-tearing-plugin